How to show that the limit of a sequence is not equal to some value?
In the second chapter of the book Understanding Analysis by Abbott, Example 2.2.6 proved that picking $N>\frac{1}{\varepsilon}$ suffices to prove the convergence of $\frac{n+1}{n}$ to the number $1$. He then continues by giving a full outline of the proof with your usual "Let $\varepsilon>0$ be arbitrary and set $N>\frac{1}{\varepsilon}$,..." At the end, he wrote a remark "It is instructive to see what goes wrong in the previous example if we try to prove that our sequence converges to some other limit other than $1$."
I have tried doing the same steps to show $\lim \frac{n+1}{n}=2$, hoping for a contradiction. I assumed that it was true, then for some $\varepsilon>0$ there is some $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq N$ we have $\left|\frac{n+1}{n}-2\right|<\varepsilon$ which reduces to the simpler expression $\left|\frac{1}{n}-1\right|<\varepsilon$. I proceeded by letting $n=N$, and with the reverse triangle inequality I obtained $N>\frac{1}{\varepsilon+1}$. However, I'm not seeing where I'm supposed to go wrong here, as Abbott claimed in his remark. Any help resolving this issue? Where am I supposed to go wrong here?

Take $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2}$, for example.

The mistake in your question is "then for some $\varepsilon>0$". It is for every $\varepsilon>0$. So if the claim was true, you should be able to find such an $N$ for any $\varepsilon>0$. Note that you can remove the absolute value easily.

I will clarify my comment. By definition, $l$ is the limit of the sequence $a_n$ if for every $\varepsilon>0$ you can find $N$ such that $\left|a_n-l\right|<\varepsilon$ for all $n>N$. Thus, in this case, $2$ would be the limit of $a_n=\frac{n+1}{n}$ if for every $\varepsilon>0$ you can find $N$ such that $\left|\frac{1}{n}-1\right|<\varepsilon$ for all $n>N$. To contradict this statement, it is sufficient to show that for at least one value of $\varepsilon>0$ you cannot find such $N$. Firstly, observe that for all $n\in\mathbb{N} \left|\frac{1}{n}-1\right|=1-\frac{1}{n}$. Hence we want to check if for every $\varepsilon>0$ (as small as you want) we can find $N$ such that $1-\frac{1}{n}<\varepsilon$ for all $n>N$.
The idea is that increasing $n$ makes $1-\frac{1}{n}$ closer and closer to $1$ and not $0$. Take for example $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2}$. Suppose that the claim is true. Firstly observe that for $N=3$ you would get $$\frac{2}{3}=1-\frac{1}{3}<\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2}$$ which is clearly false. You may want to verify if another $N^*$ works. But this is not the case. In fact, you should look for an $N^*>3$ such that $1-\frac{1}{n}<\frac{1}{2}$ for all $n>N^*$
(taking $N^*=1$ or $N^*=2$ does not make sense because we have already checked that the condition is not satisfied for    $n=3$, so in particular it is not satisfied for all $n>N^*$). However, $$1-\frac{1}{n} > 1-\frac{1}{N^*}>1-\frac{1}{3} = \frac{2}{3} > \frac{1}{2}$$
which means the limit is not $2$.

Sorry for editing multiple times but I wanted to be as clear as possible
